# Handle unexpected data in event listeners such as WebSocket.onmessage

Tags: javascript, websocket, dom-events

How do I handle unexpected things such as weird data, corrupted data, unexpected data, or something going wrong in an event listener.

`WebSocket` exposes a `onmessage` event listener. If it were to receive something unexpected, how is this to be dealt with?
By throwing an exception, logging to console, silently ignoring it?

- If the event listener throws an exception, then I guess there is nothing to catch that exception. Is that bad?
- Use `console.log` in production is bad?
- If the event listener silently ignore the message? Isn't that bad?

```js
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://www.example.com/');
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    if (event.data === 'GARBAGE') {
        // What is the appropriate thing to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your application and how critical the problem is.

- Generally, putting output to console for production, especially errors, is not such a good thing. End-users might not like seeing "error" or "exception" in the console log, especially, if the application handles some sensitive information.
- One have to be careful in using console.log, especially, if printing some variables, as you may introduce some memory leaks.

Ignoring an error should be a choice by design. If you are receiving an unexpected data to the listener, it means that your system is not working as intended somewhere. At least, you should know why you are getting such input.

Comment: If the client receives unexpected data, it might be because anyone who uses the library uses it together with a buggy server.

Comment: That is fine. What are the implications for the system/user when he receives such an input?

Comment: The client would be confused and not know what to do with the data. Perhaps fail because something is `undefined`. Either way, shouldn't the client library somehow alert user of the library that what the server sent is unexpected?

Comment: If it is a library, then, in its productized form, it should do one of the following: return error codes for failures, throwing an exception. Meaning of the errors/exceptions should be described in the accompanying documentation. Those could be used by application to handle the error correctly. Console log is only helpful for debugging.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a normal function. This is a event listener function, hence I do not know if throwing an exception is appropriate since there is nothing to catch it.

Comment: It all depends on your application. In my application, websocket service is implementing the publish-subscribe model. I could subscribe error listener, that would essentially be interested in any unrecognized events or errors  and act accordingly. If, on the other hand, application is not subscribed to errors, those will be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, you can subscribe to errors, but I am talking about if the server misbehaves and sends malformed data to the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126269/discussion-between-vladimir-m-and-fred).